# executing a linux command from a TCL file

Tags: linux, tcl

I want to run a command inside a tcl file. According to [Unix examples](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm#M28), I wrote:

```
....
exec export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-4.1.2-built/lib64
puts $gofile "#!/bin/bash
....
```

However I get this error:

```
couldn't execute "export": no such file or directory
while executing
"exec export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-4.1.2-built/lib64"
```

If i remove that exec line, there is no error.

Comment: exec expects the name of a binary. Export is a shell build in  command. try something line : exec sh -c "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-4.1.2-built/lib64 ...."

Comment: @tigran That won't work, because environment variables are only inherited from parent to child. Whatever the sh process does with it's environment, it won't affect the Tcl process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set an environment variable, you don't use `exec` but rather just write to the appropriate element of the global `env` associative array (the `::` is “this is a global variable” and can be omitted if you're writing a top-level script):

```
set ::env(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) "/opt/gcc-4.1.2-built/lib64"
```

Then you can just `exec` and the value will be inherited correctly:

```
puts $gofile "#!/bin/bash
...."
```

(I'm a little surprised that you're passing in a multi-line script like that, but if it works for you, that's cool. Still, I find that if I'm doing that it's usually better to split things into multiple files. It reduces the amount of head-scratching and confusion since you don't end up fighting with more levels of quoting than the minimum.)